# Memory leak while using mysql-java-drive and spring-jdbc

Tags: java, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, mysql-connector

[image: Java Process HeapDump]

[image: Nearest GC Root]

I am seeing this weird behavior where memory is not getting released in my Java application. The service uses **spring-boot-started-jdbc** (2.2.0-RELEASE), **mysql-connector-java** (8.0.18 version). Even after doing force gc, nothing is getting released and eventually, service goes OutOfMemory.
I got the Nearest GC Root using jvisualvm, all the hogged instances are related to **TransactionAspectSupport$TransactionInfo**.

Our code uses spring's **@Transactional**

```
  @Transactional(noRollbackFor = Exception.class, isolation = READ_COMMITTED)
  public void execute(RequestPayload req) throws Exception {

  }

  @TransactionalEventListener(phase = AFTER_ROLLBACK)
  public void rollBack(RequestPayload req) {

  }
```

Can someone please guide me what could be wrong or how to debug?

Comment: Please show a minimal program which reproduces the problem. (The obvious answer is that you are not closing your JDBC resources)

Comment: @tgdavies
The codebase is very big and I am not sure which part is leading to this issue. Code uses lots of [@]Transactional, rest everything is basic service code. I have updated the way we use [@]Transactional

Comment: I think the problem with the code there is more to do with the way it gets the datasource connection or the way it deals with the returned information from the database.

Comment: Create a small application which accesses the DB in the way you are using in your application and see whether the problem occurs.